# Does XmlSerializer and it's associated attributes violate SOLID?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, solid-principles

At a current client, the architect is insisting on using `XmlSerializer` and it's associated attributes to serialize an object model to XML which will ultimately form the basis of a file format.

I am dead against this approach. Bear in mind that this client's staff are not highly skilled developers and the contractors were brought in specifically to implement best practices and design principles as it's a Greenfield implementation. I have been struggling to construct the arguments, until I decided to go back to base principles i.e. SOLID.

**Reason 1: XmlSerializer violates Single Responsibility Principle**

When I create a model object for my object model (i.e. class Person), I can describe the class as follows:

> Person class describes the attributes and properties of a Person within the system.

Once I add the `XmlSerializer` attributes, the description becomes:

> Person class describes the attributes and properties of a Person within the system **and**
>   how those attributes and properties are serialized to XML.

Note the **and**. Thus, violating **Single Responsility Principle**.

**Reason 2: Over the long-term, `XmlSerializer` results in classes that violate the Interface Segregation Principle**

As this is a file format, the one thing that is guaranteed over time is that file formats change and migration needs to occur - `XmlSerializer` is supremely stubborn in terms of it speaks one XML schema (based on it's attributes) and that is it. Adding attributes like `ObsoleteAnnotation` while it does not stop a normal developer from using that particular attribute, does stop the `XmlSerializer` from serializing values to/from that property (basically acting like a de facto `XmlIgnoreAttribute`!).

This is where an `XmlReader` or even `LINQ-to-XML` serialization implementation would save massive amounts of effort for the developers in terms of long-term maintenance/enhancement, despite the initial development effort and maintains the **Interface Segregation Principle** because `XmlSerializer` forces the developer to keep properties/attributes around in class interfaces that they do not use, in order to migrate from one version of a file format to another.

**Note:** I am NOT saying that use of `XmlSerializer` everywhere **is** necessarily bad design (tho' the **SRP** argument holds true for all implementations), only in the situation where interfaces are changing i.e. for a file format.

Keeping strictly to the application of SOLID principles to a changing file format and using `XmlSerializer` as the serialization technology - is my analysis of the application of SOLID principles correct?

Comment: Welcome to the reality :) There are a lot of other examples from big software vendors for violating the principles of good programming.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect of an answer, since you've basically shown in your question that it does violate some principles of SOLID. All I can say is don't treat SOLID like a dogma. If you start writing an `IMath` interface and wrapper object to inject `System.Math` into your objects then you've gone too far.

Comment: If you're fighting for purity, consider using DTO for serialization purposes to keep the model following all of principles you want. But, note, that DTOs violates even more, that you've listed... :) The reality is more complex, that all these SOLID, SRP and many many more. In fact, that's the reason, why project architects exists at all - they responsible to adapt the theory (such as design patterns or principles) to practice.

Comment: @Dirk Well, an answer could be arguments FOR using `XmlSerializer` in this specific application and why it would be good design in that case? I don't treat SOLID as a dogma, but I was trying to rationalise a gut reaction of "XmlSerializer bad" due to past experience. The architect also places high importance in SOLID which is why the argument is expressed in those terms.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are into reading books, may I recommend to you [The Pragmatic Programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pragmatic_Programmer).  This book is all about being *pragmatic* instead of *dogmatic*.

Putting attributes inside a class file to support serialization is a *pragmatic* approach, in the sense that other approaches, regardless of their perceived benefits, tend to actually have more disadvantages overall.  Harder to understand, harder to maintain, etc.

Comment: I agree about pragmatism, but in his case his requirements might justify using a more complex approach. If you have to support different versions of the serialization format then using attributes might not be a good idea.

Comment: I think this was more about rationalising my gut reaction of "XmlSerializer bad". As I said `XmlSerializer` definitely has it's uses but in the case of a changing file format, I don't think it's one of them. Also the architect seems to place high stock in SOLID so I've expressed the arguments in those terms. And thanks for the book recommendation! :)

Comment: Here is how I would solve the different versions issue: a) Append a version number to the name of the namespace which contains the serialized classes. i.e. MyModel1.  b) Once version 1 of the application has been shipped, (and therefore version 1 files have been created in the field,) LOCK the folder of the namespace in the repository, so that nobody can commit to it. c) Copy the old namespace into a new namespace and increment the number.  Any new work is now done on the new namespace.